# # 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

My Query is for generating row number and select record of them using generated row number.

My Query is like,

```
set @curRow=0;

SELECT  page_id,page_title,
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    page 
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 20000)  where page_title like 'A%' order by page_title;
```

In this Query error 1248 is accured in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear, just add an alias.

```
SELECT  page_id,page_title,
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    page 
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 20000) var_init where page_title like 'A%' order by page_title
/*---------------------------------^here^-----------------------------------------*/
```

This one

```
(SELECT @curRow := 20000)
```

needs an alias, so that MySQL can refer to it if necessary.